# How to display the maximum upload size in a WordPress single site?

Tags: uploads, media-settings

I'm working on a WordPress single site, where in front end, below a custom made form, where I have a file upload feature, I need to display the maximum upload size.

In my local Laragon WAMP setup, the PHP `post_max_size` is set to `2G`. I wanted to downgrade to only `20M` (20 mb).

After searching and reading several blog articles, I put the following code in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
<?php
// Set upload size limit to 20mb.
@ini_set('upload_max_size', '20M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');

/**
 * Filter the upload size limit for non-administrators.
 *
 * @param string $size Upload size limit (in bytes).
 *
 * @return int         Filtered size limit.
 */
function wpse_control_upload_size_limit( $size ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return 20971520; // 20mb to binary bytes.
    }

    return $size;
}

add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'wpse_control_upload_size_limit', 20 );
```

With this code in action, with a non-admin user I can see the Admin panel **Upload New Media** page is showing: `Maximum upload file size: 20 MB.`

Issue is: I want to display the same maximum file size limit information on my front end from.

What I tried so far is putting the following code in `functions.php`:

```
var_dump(@ini_get('post_max_size'));
```

But this is getting the `2G` limit as it's not getting the WordPress setup.

I also tried by hooking this code in `upload_size_limit` with no luck:

```
add_action( 'upload_size_limit', function() {
    var_dump( @ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );
});
```

I know there's a plugin named [Increase Maximum Upload File Size](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/), but I don't want to use a plugin for this feature. I'm also aware that, in multisite we've setup data from where we can get the maximum upload size.

But how can I display the maximum upload size on a front page form in single WordPress instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually lies on the same page where you inspected your modifications: `/wp-admin/media-new.php`.

If you get to the `/wp-admin/media-new.php` file, you will get a [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_upload_form/):

```
<?php media_upload_form(); ?>
```

And the function is located in `/wp-admin/includes/media.php`, where [you will get](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3.2/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L2060) the following line:

```
$max_upload_size = wp_max_upload_size();
```

So the holly grail you are searching is: [`wp_max_upload_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_max_upload_size/).

So you can easily follow the core, and display the maximum uploaded size anywhere with the following bit of code (thanks to the core):

```
<?php
$max_upload_size = wp_max_upload_size();
if ( ! $max_upload_size ) {
    $max_upload_size = 0;
}

/* translators: %s: Maximum allowed file size. */
printf( __( 'Maximum upload file size: %s.', 'wpse355118' ), esc_html( size_format( $max_upload_size ) ) );
?>
```